# Crear una consulta que muestre los campos todos los campos, incluyendo los campos null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buen día, soy nuevo aquí en la comunidad y como desarrollador web,
Quería ver si pueden ayudarme a crear una consulta que me permita seleccionar todos los registros de una tabla, pero tiene campos que esta null, quiero que esos campos también sean incluidos y que sean mostrados

aqui les muestro la consulta que diseñe:

```
SELECT listadocs.*, documentos.Nombre_doc FROM listadocs LEFT JOIN documentos ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc
```

Esta consulta me mostrara los siguientes registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es una comparación entre las dos tablas listados y documentos, en donde me muestre si coincide el nombre del documento, intente poniendo una clausula WHERE con el objetivo de que me los muestre según el id de una tabla llamada contratistas, que esta relacionada con la tabla documentos:

```
SELECT listadocs.*, documentos.Nombre_doc FROM listadocs LEFT JOIN documentos ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc WHERE id = 2
```

Me lo muestra de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, ahora solo me selecciona los registros que coinciden en ambas tablas, entonces lo que quiero es que aparezca el listado completo del campo `nom_doc` y que en el listado `Nombre_doc` aparezcan tanto los que si están registrados, como los que están NULL

Les agradecería mucho si me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega a tu SQL `SELECT listadocs.*, documentos.Nombre_doc FROM listadocs LEFT JOIN documentos ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc` que se muestre el valor de `id`. Puede realmente su valor sea `null` (no coincida).

```
SELECT listadocs.*, documentos.Nombre_doc, documentos.id FROM listadocs LEFT JOIN documentos ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc
```

Me da la impresión que realmwente es que no hay coincidencia en el `ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc` para los registros que son null; por ello al aplicar el where no se muestra; ahora que si quieres se muestren poniendo el `WHERE`; entonces, realiza lo siguiente:

```
SELECT listadocs.*, documentos.Nombre_doc 
FROM listadocs 
LEFT JOIN documentos ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc 
WHERE IFNULL(id, 2) = 2
```

O simplemente le pides te incluya los que donde `id` no tienen coincidencia:

```
SELECT listadocs.*, documentos.Nombre_doc 
FROM listadocs 
LEFT JOIN documentos ON listadocs.id_nomdoc = documentos.id_nomdoc 
WHERE id = 2 OR id IS NULL
```

Comment: eso era exactamente lo que necesitaba!!!!, muchísimas gracias, tal y como tu lo dijiste, utilizando la ultima consulta, me muestra los todos los campos, incluyendo los nulos, dado a mi falta de experiencia de SQL, carezco de ciertos conocimientos o funciones, gracias amigo